# JSON parse error gives something like "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line "

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am using below `ajax jquery` code

```
$('#frm_manage_staff').on('change', '#ddn_staff', function () {
            var ddn_staff = $('#ddn_staff').val();
            if (ddn_staff !== '' && $.isNumeric(ddn_staff)) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '<?php echo base_url('ledger/get_staff_detail'); ?>',
                    data: 'ledger_id=' + encodeURIComponent(ddn_staff),
                    datatype: 'json',
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $('#ddn_staff_waiting').html('<img src="<?php echo base_url('images/loader.GIF'); ?>">');
                    },
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        data = JSON.parse(data);
                        $('#roles_container').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
                        if (data.status === 'success') {
                            $('#txt_user_name').val(data.username);
                            if (data.roles !== '') {
                                var roles = data.roles.split(',');
                                if (roles.length > 0) {
                                    $('#roles_container').find(':checkbox').each(function () {
                                        for (var i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
                                            if ($(this).val() === roles[i]) {
                                                $(this).prop('checked', true);
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });

                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            $('#txt_user_name').val('');
                        }

                        $('#ddn_staff_waiting').html('');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

The php returns json which I can see in firebug like this::

```
{"status":"success","username":"dfdf","roles":"manage_shows_view,cash_inward,contra_entry"}
```

But it gives error "`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at..`".
The problem is probably on this line: "`data = JSON.parse(data);`"

Comment: you already specify `datatype: 'json',` which will parse json internally for you - no need for `data = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: Are you sure you see a _string_ in firebug, and not a JS object, because if `data` is already parsed, then `JSON.parse(data)` evaluates to `JSON.parse('[object Object]');` which is, of course, invalid JSON

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem How to know whether it is a string or object in Firebug ?

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ I removed it but it did not work, when I alert data.status it says undefined

Comment: you can do a `console.log(data)` - you will be able to tell if it's an object or a string in the firebug console

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ It returns {"status":"success","username":"","roles":"manage_shows_view,cash_inward,contra_entry"} in console.log, so basically its string

Comment: there's something else then if that's the data you're getting back.  it works fine when I run in manually in the console `console.log(JSON.parse('{"status":"success","username":"","roles":"manage_shows_view,cash_inward,contra_‌​entry"}'));`

Comment: @D555: what does `console.log(typeof data);` tell you? is the output `string` or `object`, if it yields `object`, then just ditch the `JSON.parse` bit, and you're good to go

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem console.log(typeof data) says its string, and hence I am using JSON.parse(data) but it still says SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data